# Get all body elements with javascript and loop

Tags: javascript, html, dom, web

What is the "fastest" (most efficient) way to have all elements of the body in an array and afterwards loop through each one of them?

Comment: Do you want the full DOM tree or just its first level?

Comment: Do you need the array afterwards or you just want to iterate over all nodes?

Answer (score 3):

You can use star selector in jquery.

```
var allElems=$('body').find('*');
```

allElems will be array like object so you can make a for loop on it or you can use jquery each method to go through all. like

```
allElems.each(function(){
     var elm=this, //javascript DOM object
         $elm=$(this) //jquery object for element.

});
```

If you just want to do with javascript you can use querySelectorAll dom method.

```
var allElems=document.body.querySelectorAll('*'); // new browser support
```

or

```
var allElems=document.body.getElementsByTagName('*'); //all browser support
```

Than you can use for loop to go through all elements.

Comment: There is no indication of jQuery at all in the OP's question.

Comment: @jfriend00 Added js solution too.

Answer (score 3):

I'd suggest this:

```
var items = document.body.getElementsByTagName("*");
for (var i = 0, len = items.length; i < len; i++) {
    // do something with items[i] here
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```
var els = document.body.querySelectorAll( '*' ),
    len = els.length, i = 0;

for ( ; i < len; i++ )
    console.log( els[i] );
```

Browser Support for querySelectorAll: http://caniuse.com/#feat=queryselector

It's interesting to note that `querySelectorAll` returns static NodeLists, differently from `getElementsByTagName`, which returns live NodeLists.

Comment: could you explain the difference between static and live nodes?

Answer (score -2):

It would be something like this:

```
var allElements = $(body).find('*');

allElements.each(function(){
   //do something
})
```